# What is the maximum dimensions of an image that can't be greater than 8000 bytes?

Tags: image, png

I need to allow my users to upload images, for which I need to show a thumbnail. I need to ensure that the thumbnail is not greater than 8000 bytes.

I'm using [nQuant](http://nquant.codeplex.com) (color quantizer producing high quality 256 color 8 bit PNG images) to quantize the image and reduce it to an 8 bit image, rather than 32 bit, thus drastically reducing the file size.

**What I want to know is what is the maximum dimension of the image that will always be under 8000 bytes?**

Currently I'm using 96 x 96 as my maximum dimensions and I have not exceeded the 8000 byte limit, but I don't know if this is because of the source images I'm testing the converter with (194 random pictures on my HD), or because of some other reason.

As I'm thinking about it now, I'm wondering if given that

```
96 * 96 = 9216 (bytes)
```

it's correct in assuming that my reasoning is mathematically wrong?

Should I consider reducing the maximum dimensions to

```
89 * 89 = 7921 (bytes)
```

For reference, this is the converter:

```cs
var fileSystemInfos = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath).GetFiles();
var i = 0;
var total = fileSystemInfos.Count();
foreach (var file in fileSystemInfos)
{
    using (var inputStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(inputStream))
        {
            var img = ResizeImage(sourceBitmap, 96, 96);

            QuantizeImage(img, memoryStream);

            var outputName = file.Name.Replace("JPG", "png");
            using (var outputStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(outputPath, outputName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                memoryStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine(++i + " of " + total);
}

private static void QuantizeImage(Bitmap bmp, MemoryStream outputFile)
{
    var quantizer = new WuQuantizer();
    using (var quantized = quantizer.QuantizeImage(bmp))
    {
        try
        {
            quantized.Save(outputFile, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // deal with error
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    int originalWidth = image.Width;
    int originalHeight = image.Height;

    // To preserve the aspect ratio
    float ratioX = (float)maxWidth / (float)originalWidth;
    float ratioY = (float)maxHeight / (float)originalHeight;
    float ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    // New width and height based on aspect ratio
    int newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);
    int newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);

    // Convert other formats (including CMYK) to RGB.
    //Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    // Draws the image in the specified size with quality mode set to HighQuality
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compression worst case is that bitmap won't be compressed at all, and you'll get overhead of gzip and PNG data structures (smallest overhead is 67 bytes).

You reason correctly that bitmap size is width * height.

256-color RGBA palette will take 1KB + few bytes of chunk overhead. Encoders can put other metadata like gamma/sRGB/ICC chunks, so amount of garbage in PNG is theoretically unbounded (you can create 1x1px image that takes megabytes).

Assuming your encoder doesn't put unnecessary data into the file you should reserve about 1120 bytes for PNG8 overhead, so maximum bitmap size is 82x82px.

Comment: Yes, I mean after compression. I'm not really familiar with the details around this stuff so it's difficult for me to ask exactly what I'm trying to get my head around. For example, with my 194 images the largest after compression is 7539 bytes. Why is that the largest file size compared to the others, and what is preventing it from being larger than 8000 bytes? Is it just luck, or is it impossible that the compressed image would never be larger than 8000 bytes?

Comment: I tested about 4600 images at 82x82 and the largest file size for all of them was 7763 bytes.. good enough!!